# Adding Fulltext index crashes MySQL Service

Tags: mysql, innodb, full-text-search

I'm trying to add a Fulltext index to a table. When I run the query,

```
ALTER TABLE thisTable ADD FULLTEXT(thisText);
```

I get the message

> SQL Error (2013): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

and the mysql service will indeed be stopped. If I restart the service and try to add the index again I get another error.

> SQL Error (1813): Tablespace for table 'thisTable/#sql-ib21134' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.

The engine is InnoDb and I run MySQL 5.6.12, so Fulltext index should be supported. The column is a TEXT column.

I'd be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction where the error is coming from.

Comment: Is there anything of interest in the [error log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-log.html)? If the log is not enabled, please enable it and reproduce the crash.

Comment: I am having the same problem with MySQL 5.7 so they DID NOT fix it apparently. I see this error in the log:

2016-07-15 12:22:36 0x7f65a97fa700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140074612139776 in file row0merge.cc line 1009
InnoDB: Failing assertion: b == &block[0] + buf->total_size

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to sort buffer size. It is known bug of mysql/mariadb/percona.
Even after many months I have reported this bug it was not fixed (we are using latest Mariadb)

Answer (score 0):

The second error happens because the table (or the fulltext [index table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html#innodb-fulltext-index)) was partially modified (or created) when the server crashed. Drop and re-create your table from scratch.

Now, why did the server crash? Hard to tell for sure, but it is likely that some buffer reached capacity. The usual suspect is [`innodb_buffer_pool_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size). Try to increase it progressively.

Comment: I tried to increase the buffer pool up to several GB, but I still can't add a fulltext index successfully.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu server 20.04,

despite reasonable logic to increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` I have idenified that **OOM Killer** killed mysql when that buffer is huge.

**OOM Killer** is a function of the Linux kernel that is intended to kill rogue processes that are requesting more memory that the OS can allocate, so that the system can survive.

Excerpt from syslog:

> **oom-kill**:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/**mysql.service**,task=**mysqld**,pid=98524,uid=114
> Jan 10 06:55:40 vps-5520a8d5 kernel: [66118.230690] Out of memory:
> Killed process 98524 (mysqld) total-vm:9221052kB, anon-rss:5461436kB,
> file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:114 pgtables:11232kB oom_score_adj:0

So this means, due tu huge innodb_buffer_pool_size setting, it is trying to allocate too big chunks of memory, too much agressiveley.

So using that fact, logic dictates to reduce size or set default values for innodb_buffer_pool_size, I have completley removed it from **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.conf** then restarted server with

```
systemctl restart mysql
```

and now adding fulltext on my 61M table is not crashing.